# In a PostgreSQL query how to filter results from a field in a join

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table structure is as follows:

Restaurants

```
| id | name    |
|----|---------|
| 1  | The Hut |
| 2  | T Burger|
```

Dishes:

```
| id | name    |
|----|---------|
| 1  | Pizza   |
| 2  | Caramel |
```

Orders:

```
| id | locatio |
|----|---------|
| 1  | New York|
| 2  | London  |
```

_RestaurantDishes:
In here, **B** represents restaurants and **A** represents dishes.
A restaurant can have many dishes. A dish can only have one restaurant.

```
| id | A | B |
|----|---|---|
| 1  | 1 | 1 |
| 2  | 1 | 2 |
```

_DishOrders:
In here, **B** represents orders and **A** represents dishes.
A dish can have many orders. An order can have many dishes.

```
| id | A | B |
|----|---|---|
| 1  | 1 | 1 |
| 2  | 1 | 2 |
```

What I want to do is, get a list of dishes from a selected list of restaurants and sort them according to the orders count. I tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT count(dishOrder.id) as myCount, dish.id, name
FROM "default$default"."Dish" dish
left join "default$default"."_RestaurantDishes" dishRestaurant on dish.id = dishRestaurant."A"
left join "default$default"."_DishOrders" dishOrder on dish.id = dishorder."A"
where "dishRestaurant"."B" in ("1", "2")
group by dish.id order by mycount desc;
```

But it gives me the error `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dishRestaurant"`. I tried many other approaches but didn't work.

Comment: How can a dish have only one restaurant? It has to be M-to-M relation, don't you think so?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach take example of Margereta-pizza it can be served more than one hotel? Correct me If you think this is wrong

Comment: @iamrajshah yes, I didn't read it carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting  **error ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dishRestaurant"** because
you used double quote in number `in ("1", "2")` which turned into column name for using double quote. you have to change it like  `in (1,2)`

```
SELECT count(dishOrder.id) as myCount, dish.id, name
FROM "default$default"."Dish" dish
left join "default$default"."_RestaurantDishes" dishRestaurant on dish.id = dishRestaurant."A"
left join "default$default"."_DishOrders" dishOrder on dish.id = dishorder."A"
where "dishRestaurant"."B" in (1, 2)
group by dish.id ,name
order by myCount desc;
```

you also used `dish.id, name` in selection but not used `name`  in group by, so you have to use that in group by

Comment: By the way, this condition `where "dishRestaurant"."B" in (1, 2)` turns the first LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN, so you can replace `left join "default$default"."_RestaurantDishes"` with `inner join "default$default"."_RestaurantDishes"`. If you really want to use LEFT JOIN, then move the condition from WHERE into ON clause: `left join "default$default"."_RestaurantDishes" dishRestaurant on dish.id = dishRestaurant."A" AND "dishRestaurant"."B" in (1, 2)`

Comment: If `dish.id` is primary key, then grouping by `dish.name` is pointless and not required.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But now I'm getting an error saying `missing FROM-clause entry for table "dishRestaurant"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape identifiers if you can avoid it.  The escaping fixes the casing -- and strange things happen.

I suspect that you want:

```
select count(*) as myCount, d.id, d.name
from "default$default"."Dish" d left join
     "default$default"."_RestaurantDishes" dr
     on dr."A" = d.id and
        dr."B" in (1, 2) left join
     "default$default"."_DishOrders" do
     on d.id = do."A"
group by d.id, d.name
order by mycount desc;
```

Notes:

- I simplified the table aliases and removed the double quotes from the aliases defined in the query.
- You should remove the double quotes from the column names -- if you can.
- I added `d.name` back into the `group by`.  This is not needed if `d.id` is unique.
- I use `count(*)`, so no columns are referenced.
- I moved the filtering condition to the `on` clause.  This keeps the `left join` intact.